# What does "protecting" a post do?

Tags: discussion, protected-question

Some of the more successful questions that have been around for years are often "protected".

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam
>   answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10
>   reputation on this site.

Could someone elaborate a bit further as to what this does and why it is put in place on older questions?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question

Comment: You may also be interested in this post; [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) if you want to learn more about the operation of the site.

Comment: "Thanks!" :P I do suppose that this meta question is part of a larger group of questions that can be answered there at the FAQ. I should have investigated further, but I appreciate you helping me understand and develop proper etiquette on here.

Comment: Happy to help. Now go answer something :-)

Comment: @Richard Can't; you've left no questions to be answered :p

Comment: @mooz - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/unanswered

Comment: @Richard Funny, I guessed that you might have said that! Oh well, if *you* haven't answered them yet, then no-one can!

Comment: @Mooz - There are a number of universes that I don't touch (for various reasons); Game of Thrones, Big Hero 6, Mass Effect, Warhammer, etc are currently in my ignore list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm just going to shamelessly plagiarise [the answer from here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/262849)

---

### What does it mean for a question to be protected?

[Protected](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/) questions have the additional restriction that [new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) are not permitted to answer the question.  Unlike [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) questions, they can still be edited, commented on, and voted on.  You can even vote to close them.

### Why are some questions protected?

Some questions are protected because they are expected to attract either spam or users -- often new users -- who may mistake the site as a traditional forum, posting "noisy" answers such as "Thank you" or "This worked for me" or "I'm also having this problem".

### Who can protect and unprotect questions?

- [Diamond moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/what-are-diamond-moderators)
- Users with at least 15,000 reputation can protect or unprotect any question at least a day old
- The system (via [the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)) will [automatically protect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers/89971#89971) a question that's had three answers from low-rep users deleted or [5 answers from low-rep users posted in the past 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226619/auto-protect-questions-that-get-more-than-n-answers-from-new-users-in-a-24-hour).

### Who can answer a protected question?

Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question. However, **the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check**, so you must have earned 10 or more reputation *on that specific site* to answer a protected question.

### When should I protect or unprotect a question?

- Do protect questions that are attracting a lot of non-answers or very poor answers (spam, etc.) from new users.
- Don’t protect questions just because they’re linked to on a high-traffic news site.
- Do unprotect questions that aren’t currently attracting a lot of attention and don’t have a long history of unproductive answers.